# How to validate a django form defined in a twitter bootstrap modal?

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I load a page in which i render a django form within a twitter bootstrap modal as follows;

```
 <!-- other half of the page -->     
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal-{{item.pk}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              ......
    <div class="modal-body">
      <form method="post" action=".">
       {% csrf_token %}
       {%for optionalcategory in item.optionalitems.all %}
        <h5 style="color: #646464; font-size: 14pt; font-weight: Bold;"> {{ optionalcategory.title }} </h5>
         {% for option in optionalcategory.optional_items.all %}
         <ul style="padding-left: 0px:">
        <li id= "item_appearence" style="font-size: 30px; color: #888888;" rel="tooltip" title="{{optionalitem.description}}" id="example"><input type="radio" value="{{optionalitem.id}}" name="option">{{option.name}}
          {% endfor %}
         {% endfor %}
       <br />
       <h5 style="color: #646464; font-size: 14pt; font-weight: Bold;">Quantity</h5>
        {{ form.quantity }}
         <br />
       <input class="btn btn-large btn-success" type="submit" id="submit_order" value="Add To Order" name="submit">
     </form>
            ...
```

I try to validate this form the normal django way but that doesnot work,it never validates at all.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = form(request.POST)   
    if form.is_valid():
         #do something
```

My **basic** understanding is the django validation cannot access the form defined in the modal as it would in a normal *.html* page. Meaning i would have to use some javascript. But having no knowledge, it makes it even more complicated.
How can i go about this, am not asking for the code to be written for me but an explanation on how i can achieve the functionality using javascript.

Comment: While your statement about the use of javascript in the modal is accurate, this should work in a trivial way (form submit should go through fine). One thing I noticed though was `li id= "item_appearence"` would cause multiple `id`, which would make the HTML generated invalid. change that to `class="item_appearence" id="item_appearence-{{forloop.counter0}}"`

Comment: So what is this trivial way to achieve the functionality. Because the obvious way is not working.

Comment: I was trying to say - the way you have set up is fine. Just note that `.` would render it to the current URL (It would go to the view corresponding to the URL you see in the browsers' address bar.).

Comment: the `.` was causing the trouble. Nice catch.